# Callback function not executing in ajax form

Tags: jquery, servlets

I am trying to submit a form using ajax to servlet.The form is submitted successfully, database entries are changed but the callback function is not getting executed.Please help.
here is my jsp page that has ajax post method

```
        $("#passwordchange").submit(function(){
        var oldprofpass = $("#profpass").val();
        var newprofpass = $("#profpassnew").val();      
        $.post("http://localhost:8080/SWMSProject/AdminpassChangeServlet",{profpass:oldprofpass,profpassnew:newprofpass},callbackfunction);
    });
```

and the callback function is

```
function callbackfunction(data)
{
   alert(data);
}
```

The servlet which is controller is

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
        boolean status = adb.adminChangePassword(e, request.getParameter("profpassnew"));
if(status)
{
out.print("Password changed successfully");
}
else
{
out.print("Please enter the old password correctly");
 }
```

The AdminBean contains logic and database connectivity. I cannot understand what problem is When i debugged using firebug the alert is coming, no errors. But not normally.Please help.

Comment: also i think there is no problem in my admin bean

Comment: I hope the code above of AdminpassChangeServlet is getting called from doPost()

Comment: yup its from doPost(). i am getting everything correct.The database operations are also working properly.only problem is the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop normal submit processing as well; when the page refreshes after the submit your Ajax post essentially goes away.

Comment: Thanks a lot. return false i was missing.